# How to exclude part of regexp with grep

Tags: regex, macos, grep

Hi suppose you have the following output from 'some_command':

```
DEPENDENCY archy@0.0.2
DEPENDENCY bower-config@~0.5.2
DEPENDENCY bower-endpoint-parser@~0.2.2
DEPENDENCY bower-json@~0.4.0
DEPENDENCY bower-logger@~0.2.2
DEPENDENCY bower-registry-client@~0.2.0
DEPENDENCY cardinal@0.4.0
DEPENDENCY chalk@0.5.0
DEPENDENCY chmodr@0.1.0
DEPENDENCY decompress-zip@0.0.8
DEPENDENCY fstream@~1.0.2
DEPENDENCY fstream-ignore@~1.0.1
DEPENDENCY glob@~4.0.2
DEPENDENCY graceful-fs@~3.0.1
DEPENDENCY handlebars@~2.0.0
DEPENDENCY inquirer@0.7.1
DEPENDENCY insight@0.4.3
DEPENDENCY is-root@~1.0.0
DEPENDENCY junk@~1.0.0
DEPENDENCY lockfile@~1.0.0
DEPENDENCY lru-cache@~2.5.0
DEPENDENCY mkdirp@0.5.0
DEPENDENCY mkdirp@^0.5.0
DEPENDENCY chalk@^0.5.0
DEPENDENCY graceful-fs@~3.0.1
DEPENDENCY mkdirp@~0.5.0
DEPENDENCY mkdirp@^0.5.0
```

What I want to do is to get the library name including version without 'DEPENDENCY' part. I'm using:

```
> some_command | grep -ioE '(?:dependency )(.+)'
```

A non-capturing group should have ignored the 'dependency' part, but it isn't.

What am I doing wrong? (I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite)

### #EDIT

In case someone might benefit from resolving th similar Mac OS X grep problems, here is the link of choice: http://www.heystephenwood.com/2013/09/install-gnu-grep-on-mac-osx.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-capturing groups is not available in `grep`. What you can do is to use a look-behind with the `-P` from Perl regexp:

```
grep -Pio '(?<=dependency )(.+)'
```

Executing it against a file with your input, it returns:

```
archy@0.0.2
bower-config@~0.5.2
bower-endpoint-parser@~0.2.2
bower-json@~0.4.0
bower-logger@~0.2.2
...
```

Since you don't have `-P`, you can use either of these other approaches (among others!):

```
sed '/^DEPENDENCY/s/^DEPENDENCY //'
awk '/^DEPENDENCY/ {print $2}'
```

They are always about printing what comes after `DEPENDENCY` if a line starts with this string.

Comment: It seems that I'm lacking Perl support, how do you install it?

Comment: You can get a GNU grep. For example my `grep (GNU grep) 2.18` has it. Otherwise, we can get some `awk` or `sed` similar behaviour. Let me know if you need it.

Comment: @Lu4 in fact, I just added those approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Non capturing part does not ignore the match, i just excludes it from match group.. You can use look behind.. with `P` switch

```
some_command | grep -ioP '(?<=dependency )(.+)'
```